# Search Box Edit Text loses focus on text input

Tags: android

I have list view with a Text & Edit Text as list view item. User need to enter a numeric value corresponding to respective text. On top of list view we have search box to find a particular item in list view. On clicking search box(edit text) the keyboard opens but after entering first alphabet, the view gets distorted (the search box moves up in the screen) and no more input is accepted from keyboard. Below is code snippet :
 Activity xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context="com.belinnov.product.tcbroms.activity.StockProductsActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/stock_layout_progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/stock_product_search_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/search_bar_height">

        <com.xxx.helper.EditTextBackEvent
            android:id="@+id/stock_product_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/app_margin_small"
            android:background="@drawable/editext_background"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:textSize="@dimen/app_font_medium"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/app_padding_large">
        </com.xxx.helper.EditTextBackEvent>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/searchsm"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_margin_regular"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_margin_regular"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/stock_product_lv"
        android:layout_below="@id/stock_product_search_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/grey"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/listview_divider_height">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The list view item xml :

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/stock_product_list_item"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/stock_pr_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".70"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_padding_small"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/app_padding_small"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stock_pr_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/app_font_medium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="aa"/>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stock_product_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/app_font_medium"/>
 </LinearLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/stock_product_qty_edt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:padding="@dimen/app_margin_regular"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_padding_small"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/app_padding_small"
        android:background="@drawable/editext_background">
        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

We have specified `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` for list view edit text. Due to this on clicking the edit text the normal keyboard open for a fraction of second and then numeric keyboard appears. Also nothing could be keyed in search box. Changed the code to request focus on search box as below :

```
searchEditText = (EditTextBackEvent) findViewById(R.id.stock_product_search);
        searchEditText.setFocusable(false);
        searchEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                searchEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

With above change the regular soft keyboard appears on search box click. But as soon as first alphabet is entered, results are filtered and whole view gets distorted (moves up, hiding the search box). On pressing back the view appears to normalcy and then on another alphabet input, same behavior. Have tried few other things too like `android:descendantFocusability` but none of them seem to be working. Struggling for quite some time now. Please advise if I am missing something.

Comment: why not use a standard `SearchView` instead of whatever this is :: `com.xxx.helper.EditTextBackEvent` ? Or maybe event a standard `EditView` with a `Button`?

Comment: Thanks. Will try as suggested.